# How can one use ansicolor with email-ext in Jenkins via JELLY_SCRIPT?

Tags: jenkins-plugins, jelly, email-ext

I have a Jenkins server with using the plugins `ansicolor` and `email-ext`.  Jenkins runs scripts with ANSI escaped text which is properly being converted to color-coded HTML on the console output of the Jenkins web GUI.

Email-ext is being used to send out emails which include the log file using the a Jelly script template which was based on the built in  `html` template (ie `Default Content` box has value `${JELLY_SCRIPT,template="html_modified"}`).  However, the log data in the email is not color coded, even though the email `Content Type` is set to `HTML`.

According to a Jelly tip in the [email-ext docs](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin), one can

> ...get object of other plugin actions by querying build actions like:
>   `${it.getAction('hudson.plugins.fitnesse.FitnesseResultsAction')}`

I think this can be used to solve the following problem, but I'm not sure how.  How can one use the `it.getAction()` function in a Jelly template to make use of `ansicolor`'s HTML emitter?  I've tried [looking at the source](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ansicolor-plugin/tree/master/src) to find what "action" I could use in the Jelly tip example.

Note that it appears the log data being acquired in the built-in `html` template uses `build.getLog(100)` which, for some reason, does *not* provide the original ANSI-escaped log text.  If such text was passed through ansicolor, it would not get HTML-tagged since there are no ANSI tags to convert.  Thus, the loop in the `html` template should pull from the log file.

Here is the `html` template snippet I'd like to modify to

1. Pull log from file instead of build.getLog(100)
2. Pass text through `ansicolor` to make it into pretty HTML

```html
<TABLE width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <TR>
    <TD class="bg1">
      <A href="${rooturl}${build.url}">${rooturl}${build.url}><B>CONSOLE OUTPUT</B></A>
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <j:forEach var="line" items="${build.getLog(100)}">
    <TR>
      <TD class="console">${line}</TD>
    </TR>
  </j:forEach>
</TABLE>
```